# reactjs function to find window size and onClick subtract 80% of it each time

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a function that will on each click move my container 80% of window width to the left.

I am using this in my state

```
left: 0
```

and this is part of the style of my container that I want to be moved, like this

```
    <div className="horizontal_container" style={{ left: props.left }}>
```

and I want to use a function that I'm passing via props that looks like this

```
  pomeranjeGalerije = () => {
    const {left} = this.state;
    left -= window.innerWidth*0,8;
    this.setState({left: left});
  }
```

this is how I pass the function via the prop

```
  <ContainerTheatre klikLevo={this.pomeranjeGalerije}/>
```

and this is the actual button

```
  <img onClick={props.klikLevo} src="xx" alt="right_arrow" />
```

I get the error message 
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression 
for the line left -= window.innerWidth*0,8;

can you please help me get the function right?

Comment: what's the actual problem?

Comment: You cannot mutate a `const`. Try `let { left } = this.state;`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error message @JackO'neill i updated the question

Comment: the let didn't work @sallf

Comment: Will you show the button or code that's calling `pomeranjeGalerije`?

Comment: @sallfI have added the code in the question if you need something else, please ask

Comment: You have a comma `,` instead of a period `.` in your assignment. Should be `left -= window.innerWidth * 0.8;`

Comment: the error message is probably because of `0,8` instead of `0.8`. For the rest, see my answer

Comment: you are right, thank you @sallf

Comment: thank you @JackO'neill that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several problems in your code.

- You have to use the decimal point instead of a comma. So use `0.8` instead of `0,8`.
- You also have to access your left-value from `state.left` instead of `props.left`.
- Your calculation of left doesn't make much sense. I change that so your div has the initial value of window.innerWidth and shrinks to 80% of its previous value on each button click.

:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class YourComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { left: window.innerWidth };
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    }

    buttonClick() {
        let newWidth = this.state.left * 0.8;
        console.log('new width is', newWidth);
        this.setState({left: newWidth });
    }

    render() {
        return (<div style={{"background": "#ff0000", "width": this.state.left + "px", "left": this.state.left}}>
            <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Shrink to 80% of Width</button>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: The left value is passed to a component thats why its props. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but this code will create a container component that when clicked on will shrink to 80% of the window. If it's not exactly the same as what you want, it can at least give you an idea of what to do.

```js
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            left:window.innerWidth
        }
    }

    onClick=()=>{
        var left = (this.state.left)-window.innerWidth*0.2;
        this.setState({left: left});
        console.log(left)
    }
    render () {

        return(
            <div style={{width:this.state.left+"px",backgroundColor:'red'}} onClick={this.onClick}>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this is similar to what I need but its still missing one thing. On every onClick, I want to move the container to the left for -(window.innerWidth*0.8). So on every onClick, I need to add -(window.innerWidth*0.8) to the left. 
the mistake was the comma, they solved it above thank you